# Make Angular Pure Pipe refresh itself

Tags: angular, typescript

**Is it possible for pure pipe to refresh it's returned value internally?**

I'd like my pure pipe to have an internal subscription and refresh returned value periodically. Unluckily, as I understand, only parent component can call transform method of pipe (when input changes), so pipe cannot refresh itself.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qx2jzq?file=src/main.ts

```
@Pipe({ name: 'purePipe', pure: true})
export class Pure {
  value = 0;

  constructor(service: Service, cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    service.subject.subscribe((val) => {
      this.value = val; // I'd like to refresh returned value
      cd.detectChanges();
    });
  }

  transform(input: number) {
    return this.value; // Since I return by value, not reference, I can't refresh
                       // transform() is called only when input changes,
                       // so I can't call it from inside
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do what you're looking for.

The `Pipe.transform` is called during the ChangeDetection cycle.

By making your pipe `pure: true`, CD won't call your pipe unless its input value changes. (which isn't the case here).

Since you're caching your value within the pipe, you can make your pipe unpure, the cost will be negligeable. That's exactly how the `AsyncPipe` works. It is unpure and caches the subscribes values.

Comment: Thanks, I agree that this is a solution, but tbh I considered this makes the pipe a little cryptic to use.

Comment: Please see my edit, just make your pipe unpure.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I was checking that impure pipe works effortlessly on attached stackblitz, still I just couldn't find a specific info that this will be impossible to make with pure pipe without some boilerplate. 


I'm making something similar to ngx translate pipe and they're also using impure pipe.